# I want to know which sentence is correct

Tags: grammar

> The children were given these books by the city.

I want to change this sentence.

> To the children were given the books by the city.

OR

> To the children the books were given by the city.

Which is correct?

Comment: Why do you want to change it? The first one is best, third one is OK but sounds odd, and its unlikely you will hear anyone use the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, neither sentence is technically *wrong* (depending heavily on your definition of "wrong"), but the second would be slightly more correct in terms of legibility. That said, the sentence structure of both modifications is still very confusing and ambiguous and the original sentence is much clearer. I'd strongly recommend staying with the original if possible.